# NiFi: Isuue with QueryDatabaseTableRecord Component

Tags: apache-nifi

I am getting below error while processing data from a HIVE table using QueryDatabaseTableRecord Processor. Can you please help me how to resolve it if you had faced similar issue please.

"Error during database query or conversion of records"

"Database Connection Pooling Service" --> To HiveConnectionPool"

"Database Type" --> "Generic"

"RecordWriter" --> Tried with Csv and Json default setting but nothing seems like working

Please let me know how to resolve it.

Thanks,

NKumar

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the SQL processors such as QueryDatabaseTableRecord will work with HiveConnectionPool controller services. The Hive JDBC driver does not implement the full JDBC API, and many of our SQL processors call JDBC methods that are not supported by Hive. That's why there are Hive-specific processors such as SelectHiveQL (although I do realize there's no QueryHiveTableRecord at the time of this writing)

Are you seeing a particular error on the processor or controller service in the logs? If so can you share them here?

Comment: Thanks Matt. I can sense that component is trying to run the query but failing to fetch the resultset with below message.
"Error during database query or conversion of records"
Basically I need to extract data from HIVE table on a continous basis with only changes done on table recently (Using some book marking fields). Is there any other component you suggest.